# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type styles

Tags: typescript, react-native

It complains:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type styles

```
type props = {
  type: string
}

const style = styles[props.type]

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  base: {
    ...spacing.medium,
    padding: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 50,
  },
  primary: {
    backgroundColor: colors.purple,
    color: colors.white,
  },
  secondary: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    color: colors.purple,
    borderColor: colors.purple,
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`props` is a type, therefore it's not "real".  It's there to tell Typescript what and what not to accept, and will be stripped out of the code during transpilation.  So, you can't use it to access an object property.

If you add more detail on what you are trying to achieve, it would be possible to help you get there.